# WebService síncrono

Tags: java, web-service

Tenho um WebService RESTful desenvolvido em Java.

Preciso que um método (serviço) que seja síncrono. Mas não posso fazer isso do lado do cliente, tem que ser feito do lado do WebService, pois este serviço só pode ser requisitado uma única vez por vez. Outra aplicação só pode requisitar o método (serviço) se ele não estiver em execução.

Como posso fazer isso do lado do WebService?

Comment: Qual base de frameworks você utiliza Spring ou JavaEE?

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta me pareceu confusa. Mas se eu entendi bem o que você quer é que o método não possa estar sendo executado duas vezes ao mesmo tempo mesmo que por clientes diferentes.

Assim sendo, o uso de um bloco `synchronized` resolverá o seu problema caso só tenha um único processo servidor atendendo requisições. Por exemplo:

```
public class MeuServico {

    private static final Object bloqueio = new Object();

    public void meuMetodo() {
        synchronized (bloqueio) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Se houver vários processos atendendo requisições, a situação fica um pouco mais complicada. Neste caso você pode ter um banco de dados com uma tabela contendo uma única linha e uma única coluna para simular o *mutex*  representado acima. O conteúdo deste dado é um identificador que diz quem é que está executando o método no momento.